# Hide WooCommerce Storefront on frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

I developed this custom theme of mine in WordPress a couple of months ago, knowing I later would be integrating WooCommerce/Storefront on my website. However, now making my theme a "Storefront template" I am experiencing major issues with the whole setup. You see, even though I have a custom index.php page with a specific structure, storefront just overrides it and shows up in full-width on my website - even though I have not set a parent theme.

My website is a small blog, with a custom index (index.php), an archive (archive.php), and a single post page (single-post.php). The idea of the whole storefront integration, was to have a button that would take people to the "store"-part of the website. In other words, have it separated by for example having it like this: mydomain.com/store/.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction on how I would approach this? Now storefront is displaying on every single custom page of mine, and it's really frustrating. I want my "blog-page"-theme and store-theme to be separate. In other words, the header for my custom pages displays on all of the storefront pages (and the custom ones), while on my custom pages, the storefront part just overrides its main content except footer and header.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know storefront is a complete wordpress theme developed to work well with the woocommerce plugin.

When you activated storefront it became your main theme.

To use your own designed header and footer within the storefront theme, you should create a "child theme" for storefront. This way you can overwrite the default storefront elements with your own custom elements.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/